# Typeface display issue with Firefox but not Safari

Tags: fonts, webfonts

I have a display issue with a custom typeface I'm using with font2web's service... The typeface consists of icons and was put together by myself (Not sure if that is relevant.) And in a nut shell they are not displaying right in firefox... even in chrome they seem a tad off but not as badly, while in safari they look fine. They were fine in each browser at first but now they seem to be shifted/distorted...

I've isolated the icons in an html file here and the problem persists. www.robinwkurtz.com/test/icons.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com) over most any other web font tool. And look at the source code that Font Squirrel creates compared to Font2Web & see what might be choking one over another… Assuming Font Squirrel does a better job.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried font squirrel in the first place but for some reason it did not work. However perhaps I just missed something that time around. I'll try again.